Is there anything special about てはいけないから / といけないから to mean "preventing a negative situation"?
Some sources like here and here have listed てはいけないから / といけないから as their own grammar to mean something like "in order to not~; to prevent a negative situation".
Here are some examples:

風邪を引くといけないから、マフラーをして出かけなさい。
明日忘れ物をしてはいけないから鞄の中を何度も確認する。
彼女は体重が増えてはいけないからダイエットをしている。
失敗するといけないから予備にするものが必要だ。

What I wonder is if there is anything special about てはいけないから / といけないから to be used in these situations in comparison to forms like てはならない. It just seems somewhat unnecessary to list these forms alongside から as if the grammar is special or something.

When used without から, てはいけない (and てはならない) typically mean prohibition while といけない does concern/fear/worry. So it seems not clear to leaners and hence worth mentioning that those expressions mean (almost) the same when used with から.

I don't think there is anything special. This is a simple combination of てはいけない/といけない and から.
However, note that てはならない has a formal and prohibitive tone, so it doesn't match well with your casual examples that aren't really about "rules".
